# Clojure routing , bidi , the regexes I use for routes aren't being matched perfectly

Tags: regex, clojure, routes, bidi

I need some help with constructing some routes, I have the following route schema,

```
   (def my-routes

        ["/" {"" :home

              "info" :info

              "posts/" {"" :all-posts

                        [#"\d+" :tag-name] :post-by-tag

                        [#"\w+" :post-name] :post-by-name}}])
```

but when I do some tests it seems there is a problem with the regex. For example :

```
    ;; testing the tag route
    (match-route my-routes "/posts/213")
    ;; => {:route-params {:tag-name "3"}, :handler :post-by-tag}

    ;; testing the name route
    (match-route my-routes "/posts/the-first-post")
    ;; => {:route-params {:post-name "-first-post"} , 
                          :handler :post-by-name}
```

So it seems to cut off the part after the "/" , and when I do it outside of bidi on a normal re-matches check it seems fine

```
    (re-matches #"\d+" "213")
     ;; => "213"

    ;; I do see that this regex wouldn't pass the example I used above, but 
    ;; the main matter is this weird behaviour seen in the routing.
    (re-matches #"\w+" "post")
    ;; => "post"
```

If anyone could provide some regex that parse these routes it would be much appreciated

*Edit* :

After replacing the regex and trying it with `match-route` it seems to only return the last letter:

```
(use 'bidi.bidi)
;; => nil

(def my-routes
  ["/" {"" :home

        "info" :info

        "posts/" {"" :all-posts
                  [#"\d+" :tag-name] :post-by-tag
                  [#"[\w\-]+" :post-name] :post-by-name}

        }]

)
;; => #'user/my-routes

(match-route my-routes "/posts/the-first-post")
;; => {:route-params {:post-name "t"}, :handler :post-by-name}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` does not match the minus sign:

```
(re-matches #"\w+" "the-first-post" )
=> nil
```

You probably want to use `[\w\-]` instead:

```
(re-matches #"[\w\-]+" "the-first-post" )
"the-first-post"
```

Comment: While this passes re-matches, it doesn't work for bidi and all that's accompanying the :post-name key is "t"

Comment: Did you use #”[\w\-]+“ with the plus sign ?

Comment: I have, I've edited the post to shown what I've tried